# Use iterators with custom-made vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, iterator

I have created a custom vector which I would like to create an iterator for, I have reduced the code to a minimalistic version with only one error left. I would like to fix that error then make the code do what it is supposed to do which is print the sum of the elements of the array.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



template <class Elem>
class ArrayVector{
    public :
        ArrayVector(){
            A = new Elem[3];
            A[0] = 1;
            A[1] = 2;
            A[3] = 3;
            ptr = &A[0];
        }
        const ArrayVector * begin(){
            this->begin();
        }
    class iteratorArray{
            Elem * current;
            const ArrayVector * begin(){
                return iteratorArray();
            }
            const ArrayVector* end(){  
                iteratorArray* end = new iteratorArray(&current[3]);
                return end;
            }
            iteratorArray(Elem* initLoc){
                current = initLoc;
            }
            iteratorArray operator+(int n){
                current = &current[n];
                return *this;
            }
            bool operator!=(iteratorArray& obj2){
                return this->current != obj2.current;
            }
            iteratorArray operator++(){
                current = current+1;
                return *this;
            }
            Elem& operator*(){
                return *current;
            }
    };
    Elem* A;
    Elem* ptr;
};


int main() {
    ArrayVector<int> vector1;
    typedef ArrayVector<int>::iteratorArray iteratorArray;  
    int sum = 0;
    for (iteratorArray p = vector1.begin(); p != vector1.end(); ++p)
        sum += *p;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Your `ArrayVector` doesn't have any `begin` and `end` functions - you defined those as members of `iteratorArray`

Comment: Since you are new here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For questions like your's, it is further required to extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, you made a mistake, you bit off too much to chew. Take smaller, incremental steps instead, like e.g. leaving off the whole `template ...` stuff. Further, in order to track your progress, consider "Test-Driven Development" (seach the web for that!), it is an invaluable technique for many programming tasks.

Comment: Why do you have `delete [] A;` in your `ArrayVector` copy constructor?  The object is brand new, so what is there to `delete`?

Comment: Your `begin` function lacks a `return` and it's not even declared to return the iterator, but instead a pointer to an `ArrayVector`

Comment: `A[3] = 3;` is going out of bounds of the array. You meant to use `A[2] = 3;` instead. That said, you don't really need `iteratorArray` at all. You can just use raw pointers instead, those are perfectly valid iterators. `ArrayVector::begin()` can return `&A[0]` and `ArrayVector::end()` can return `&A[3]`.

Comment: I need to use iterators for my college homework

Answer (score 0):

You implemented your `iteratorArray` all wrong.  It should look more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class Elem>
class ArrayVector{
private:
    Elem* A;

public :
    ArrayVector(){
        A = new Elem[3];
        A[0] = 1;
        A[1] = 2;
        A[2] = 3;
    }

    ArrayVector(const ArrayVector &src){
        A = new Elem[3];
        A[0] = src.A[0];
        A[1] = src.A[1];
        A[2] = src.A[2];
    }

    ~ArrayVector(){
        delete[] A;
    }

    ArrayVector& operator=(const ArrayVector &rhs){
        A[0] = rhs.A[0];
        A[1] = rhs.A[1];
        A[2] = rhs.A[2];
        return *this;
    }

    class iterator {
    private:
        Elem * current;

    public:
        iterator(Elem* initLoc){
            current = initLoc;
        }

        iterator operator+(int n) const {
            return iterator(current + n);
        }

        iterator operator-(int n) const {
            return iterator(current - n);
        }

        iterator& operator++(){
            ++current;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator++(int){
            return iterator(current++);
        }

        iterator& operator--(){
            --current;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator--(int){
            return iterator(current--);
        }

        iterator& operator+=(int n){
            current += n;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator& operator-=(int n){
            current -= n;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const{
            return current != rhs.current;
        }

        Elem& operator*(){
            return *current;
        }

        // and so on for other operators that a RandomAccess iterator needs to implement...
    };

    iterator begin(){
        return iterator(A);
    }

    iterator end(){
        return iterator(A+3);
    }
};

int main() {
    ArrayVector<int> vector1;
    typedef ArrayVector<int>::iterator iteratorArray;  
    int sum = 0;
    for (iteratorArray p = vector1.begin(); p != vector1.end(); ++p)
        sum += *p;
    std::cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/6ZWSPS)

That said, you don't really need a custom `iterator` at all. You can just use raw pointers instead, those are perfectly valid iterators. `ArrayVector::begin()` can return `A` and `ArrayVector::end()` can return `A+3`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class Elem>
class ArrayVector{
private:
    Elem* A;

public :
    ArrayVector(){
        A = new Elem[3];
        A[0] = 1;
        A[1] = 2;
        A[2] = 3;
    }

    ArrayVector(const ArrayVector &src){
        A = new Elem[3];
        A[0] = src.A[0];
        A[1] = src.A[1];
        A[2] = src.A[2];
    }

    ~ArrayVector(){
        delete[] A;
    }

    ArrayVector& operator=(const ArrayVector &rhs){
        A[0] = rhs.A[0];
        A[1] = rhs.A[1];
        A[2] = rhs.A[2];
        return *this;
    }

    typedef Elem* iterator;

    iterator begin(){
        return A;
    }

    iterator end(){
        return A+3;
    }
};

int main() {
    ArrayVector<int> vector1;
    typedef ArrayVector<int>::iterator iteratorArray;  
    int sum = 0;
    for (iteratorArray p = vector1.begin(); p != vector1.end(); ++p)
        sum += *p;
    std::cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/KnnJat)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of you program changed enough to be functional. I moved the iterator out and made it a template because it doesn't really depend on `ArrayVector`. Iterators are meant to be copied by value. You can see a working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a3433941a31b6fd).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class Elem>
class iteratorArray{
    Elem * current;
public:
    iteratorArray(Elem* initLoc){
        current = initLoc;
    }
    iteratorArray operator+(int n){
        current = &current[n];
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator!=(iteratorArray const& obj2){
        return this->current != obj2.current;
    }
    iteratorArray operator++(){
        current = current+1;
        return *this;
    }
    Elem& operator*(){
        return *current;
    }
};

template <class Elem>
class ArrayVector{
public :
    ArrayVector(){
        A = new Elem[3];
        A[0] = 1;
        A[1] = 2;
        A[2] = 3;
        ptr = &A[0];
    }

    const iteratorArray<Elem> begin(){
        return iteratorArray<Elem>(ptr);
    }
    const iteratorArray<Elem> end(){  
        return  iteratorArray<Elem>(ptr + 3);
    }

    Elem* A;
    Elem* ptr;
};
```